# How do I secure scripts run using javax.scripting?

Tags: javascript, security, javax.script, server-side-scripting

I am using `javax.scripting` to add support for running arbitrary user-uploaded JavaScripts on the server-side.  Obviously I want to secure those scripts!

Rhino, on it's own, has a framework for securing scripts at runtime.  The documentation for `javax.scripting`, however, doesn't mention security, permissions or restricting classes available to the script.  So is this just a huge hole in the `javax.scripting` API that it doesn't offer a framework to secure scripts it executes?

I don't want to use Rhino directly because I originally tried that but had some problems exposing Java instances to the running script.  The `javax.scripting` framework made it (which uses Rhino under the hood) made this trivial and also simplified running scripts in a multi-threaded server.

I would like to white-list Java classes that can be accessed/instantiated within the running script.  Can anyone point me to an example or documentation on how to achieve this?

Answer (score 19, accepted):

It turns out that `javax.scripting` does not offer a security framework.  After some searching I found a document in Google's cache that suggested trying to use Java's `doPrivilegedAction` framework but after some experimentation, I was unable to get this to prevent the scripts from opening sockets or accessing the filesystem.

After I asked this question I discovered it was previously asked here on StackOverflow: [How can you run Javascript using Rhino for Java in a sandbox?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/93911/how-can-you-run-javascript-using-rhino-for-java-in-a-sandbox)  On that page, it falsely indicates that the Rhino included in the JDK6 has security worked out already.  As I indicated, I was able to open sockets and other harmful actions from the script.

In the end I abandoned `javax.scripting` and embedded Rhino directly.  By building a custom `ContextFactory` that is also a `ClassShutter` I was able to achieve two results easily:

1. Restricts script execution time to a maximum time limit
2. Restricts class access to those I have white-listed, which is basically `java.lang.*` and a select few classes in my server's hierarchy.

CodeUtopia (which I can't link to because, as a new user, I'm not allowed to link to multiple pages in a single post; but it's linked in the other StackOverflow post) was valuable in describing the `ClassShutter` architecture and Rhino's own `ContextFactory` API page describes how to build a custom `ContextFactory`.

Answer (score 2):

http://codeutopia.net/blog/2009/01/02/sandboxing-rhino-in-java/ describes a way to sandbox rhino, and javax.scripting uses Rhino as the JS script engine so you should be able to use the above, though the package names might differ.

> I’ve been working on a Java app which
>   needed Rhino for scripting. The app
>   would need to run untrusted JavaScript
>   code from 3rd parties, so I had to
>   find a way to block access to all Java
>   methods, except the ones I wanted.
>   This would not be a problem if there
>   was an easy way to disable LiveConnect
>   - the feature of Rhino which provides java access to scripts - but there is
>   no such thing.
>
> However, after a lot of digging
>   around, I finally found a way to do
>   this without too much hacking. In
>   fact, it can be done by just extending
>   a few of the Rhino classes, and using
>   the setters provided to override some
>   of the default ones.

Answer (score 1):

FYI, this is now possible in the new Java 8 implementation of javax.scripting which uses a new engine called Nashorn. See [Secure Nashorn JS Execution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20793089/secure-nashorn-js-execution)