# Banning Java Imports from Nashorn

Tags: java, nashorn

Is it possible to ban some packages of java imports from Nashorn?

[This question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24466203/how-to-remove-java-apis-from-nashorn-engine) answered to prevent all Java API calls. But I'd like to create a java imports white list to minimize implem risks (not all java APIs)

I've seen this nashorn.args "--specialize-calls" but don't know how to use it.

Thanks for the support!

Comment: See also: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20793089/secure-nashorn-js-execution

Answer (score 0):

Yes! and Links:

- https://twitter.com/sundararajan_a/status/562086779004530688
- [Secure Nashorn JS Execution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20793089/secure-nashorn-js-execution)

Thanks a lot for your comments

Only one problem about http://openjdk.java.net/jeps/202

-> jdk8u40 not released yet by Oracle