# Can I run ECMAScript 6 from Java 9 Nashorn engine

Tags: javascript, java, nashorn

Java 9 now includes ECMAScript 6 support, as claimed by [this article](https://www.oracle.com/corporate/features/nashorn-javascript-engine-jdk9.html). However, it doesn't explain how to run it from Java with [ScriptEngine](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/javax/script/ScriptEngine.html). The linked Java magazine also doesn't explain it. The article says the following:

> To activate ES6 support, use `--language=es6` on the command line.

This does work with `jjs`, but I can't find a way how to enable this from Java code. To test it, I used the following code:

```
import javax.script.ScriptEngine;
import javax.script.ScriptEngineManager;
import javax.script.ScriptException;
...
ScriptEngine engine = new ScriptEngineManager().getEngineByMimeType("application/javascript");
try {
    engine.eval("const a = 20;");
} catch (ScriptException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

It fails with the following exception:

```
javax.script.ScriptException: <eval>:1:0 Expected an operand but found const
const a = 20;
^ in <eval> at line number 1 at column number 0
    [STACK TRACE OMITTED]
```

I've tried to list all available [ScriptEngineFactories](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/javax/script/ScriptEngineFactory.html) with this code:

```
import java.util.List;
import javax.script.ScriptEngineFactory;
import javax.script.ScriptEngineManager;
...
List<ScriptEngineFactory> factories = new ScriptEngineManager().getEngineFactories();
for (ScriptEngineFactory factory : factories) {
    System.out.println("-----------------------");
    System.out.println(factory.getLanguageName());
    System.out.println(factory.getLanguageVersion());
}
```

This outputs just the following:

```
-----------------------
ECMAScript
ECMA - 262 Edition 5.1
```

Does this mean I can't run ECMAScript 6 from Java and only using `jjs`? Or is there something I have missed?

Thanks beforehand.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

While browsing through Nashorn questions here, I stumbled upon [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/24466203/3624097). Its answers describe two ways how to pass Nashorn engine commandline arguments. [This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24470394/3624097) suggests to use [NashornScriptEngineFactory](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/jdk/nashorn/api/scripting/NashornScriptEngineFactory.html) directly, code following:

```
import javax.script.ScriptEngine;
import javax.script.ScriptException;
import jdk.nashorn.api.scripting.NashornScriptEngineFactory;
...
ScriptEngine engine = new NashornScriptEngineFactory().getScriptEngine("--language=es6");
try {
    engine.eval("const a = 20;\n"
            + "print(a);");
} catch (ScriptException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

Even though this works, it's not a nice solution because it makes you use `jdk` package which is not an officially supported package. [Another answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24467387/3624097) says you can set the arguments with system property `nashorn.args`. Code:

```
import javax.script.ScriptEngine;
import javax.script.ScriptEngineManager;
import javax.script.ScriptException;
...
System.setProperty("nashorn.args", "--language=es6");
ScriptEngine engine = new ScriptEngineManager().getEngineByName("Nashorn");
try {
    engine.eval("const a = 20;\n"
            + "print(a);");
} catch (ScriptException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

This also isn't a nice way of doing it, because it relies on:

- Nashorn engine existing which may not be the case on other Java distributions, and
- Nashorn engine being up-to-date to support the `language` command line parameter.

I, personally, prefer the first version, because it will throw a [ClassNotFoundException](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/lang/ClassNotFoundException.html) on Java 1.8 since NashornScriptEngineFactory doesn't exist there, while the second version will just silently ignore the setting of property.

Comment: I still am open to other solutions to this problem, since this is flawed and I can't accept my own answer in 48 hours.

Comment: FYI: `new NashornScriptEngineFactory()` is now deprecated