# Interrupt java thread running nashorn script

Tags: java, javascript, multithreading, nashorn

In the code below i have javascript running in a separate thread from the main one. That script is an infinite loop, so it needs to be terminated somehow. How?

Calling .cancel() is not working AFTER the script begins running. But if i call .cancel() just after the thread initialization, it will terminate it (the commented out line).

```
package testscriptterminate;

import javax.script.ScriptEngine;
import javax.script.ScriptEngineManager;
import javax.script.ScriptException;

import java.util.concurrent.ExecutorService;
import java.util.concurrent.Executors;
import java.util.concurrent.Future;

import java.util.Timer;
import java.util.TimerTask;

public class TestScriptTerminate extends TimerTask{

    private ExecutorService threads;
    private Future runScript;

    private Timer t;

    public TestScriptTerminate(){
        t = new Timer();
        t.schedule(this, 6000); //let the script run for a while before attempt to cancel

        threads = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(1);
        runScript = threads.submit(new ScriptExec());

        //runScript.cancel(true); //will cancel here, before the script had a change to run, but useless, i want to cancel at any time on demand
    }

    @Override
    public void run(){
        //after script has fully initialized and ran for a while - attempt to cancel.
        //DOESN'T WORK, thread still active
        System.out.println("Canceling now...");
        runScript.cancel(true);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        new TestScriptTerminate();
    }


}

class ScriptExec implements Runnable{

    private ScriptEngine js;
    private ScriptEngineManager scriptManager;

    public ScriptExec(){
        init();
    }

    @Override
    public void run() {
        try {
            js.eval("while(true){}");
        } catch (ScriptException ex) {
            System.out.println(ex.toString());
        }
    }

    private void init(){
        scriptManager = new ScriptEngineManager();
        js = scriptManager.getEngineByName("nashorn");
    }
}
```

Comment: Nashorn should really check the interrupted status of the thread, which should be set by the `Future.cancel(true)` call, but it seems it doesn't do this. You may be able to submit this as a bug.

Comment: Yeah, i will report it...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

JavaScript (under Nashorn), like Java, will not respond to an interrupt in the middle of a tight loop. The script needs to poll for interruption and terminate the loop voluntarily, or it can call something that checks for interruption and let `InterruptedException` propagate.

You might think that Nashorn is "just running a script" and that it should be interrupted immediately. This doesn't apply, for the same reason that it doesn't apply in Java: asynchronous interruption risks corruption of the application's data structures, and there is essentially no way to avoid it or recover from it.

Asynchronous interruption brings in the same problems as the long-deprecated `Thread.stop` method. This is explained in this document, which is an updated version of the document linked in the comments.

[Java Thread Primitive Deprecation](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/technotes/guides/concurrency/threadPrimitiveDeprecation.html)

See also Goetz, *Java Concurrency In Practice*, Chapter 7, *Cancellation and Shutdown*.

The easiest way to check for interruption is to call `Thread.interrupted()`. You can call this quite easily from JavaScript. Here's a rewrite of the example program that cancels the running script after five seconds:

```
public class TestScriptTerminate {

    ScheduledExecutorService pool = Executors.newScheduledThreadPool(2);

    void script() {
        ScriptEngineManager scriptManager = new ScriptEngineManager();
        ScriptEngine js = scriptManager.getEngineByName("nashorn");
        try {
            System.out.println("Script starting.");
            js.eval("while (true) { if (java.lang.Thread.interrupted()) break; }");
            System.out.println("Script finished.");
        } catch (ScriptException ex) {
            ex.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    void init() throws Exception {
        Future<?> scriptTask = pool.submit(this::script);
        pool.schedule(() -> {
            System.out.println("Canceling now...");
            scriptTask.cancel(true);
        }, 5, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
        pool.shutdown();
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        new TestScriptTerminate().init();
    }
}
```

Since we're starting up a thread pool, might as well make it a scheduled thread pool so that we can use it for both the script task and the timeout. That way we can avoid `Timer` and `TimerTask`, which are mostly replaced by `ScheduledExecutorService` anyway.

The usual convention when handling and interrupt is either to restore the interrupt bit or to let an `InterruptedException` propagate. (One should *never* ignore an interrupt.) Since breaking out of the loop can be considered to have completed the handling of the interrupt, neither is necessary, and it seems sufficient simply to let the script exit normally.

This rewrite also moves a lot of work out of the constructor into an `init()` method. This prevents the instance from being leaked to other threads from within the constructor. There is no obvious danger from this in the original example code -- in fact, there almost never is -- but it's always good practice to avoid leaking the instance from the constructor.

Comment: Thank you for the exhaustive reply. It all makes sense to me and i've learned something new.

Now, the whole design of the script thread should be dictated by the fact that you, a user, or someone else, might not be insightful enough to gracefully check for the interrupted flag - thus the need to force it to shutdown regardless of corruption to some data structures - if such have been /allowed to be/ exposed to the script.

That is why i used the blank while(true){} to simulate essentially a blocking operation that needs to be killed if it hangs.

Comment: designing VM (in a VM) like that is dumb though. There is really easy way to terminate custom VM without dataloss

Answer (score 5):

So this is old, but i just wrote this up and thought it would probably be valuable to share. By default there is ~nothing you can do to stop a Nashorn script executing, `.cancel()` `Thread.stop()` `Thread.interrupt()` do nothing, but if you are willing to put in a bit of effort and are ok with rewriting some bytecode, it is achieveable. Details:

http://blog.getsandbox.com/2018/01/15/nashorn-interupt/

Comment: Nice article, is it possible to include a full working example ? :)

Comment: ive got it on my list to dump a working example up somewhere, i'll move it up the priority =)

Answer (score 4):

Unfortunately it does not work for simple infinite loops: `while (true) { }`. I tried `Thread.cancel();` does not cause the thread to exit. I wanted something foolproof for running scripts in an IntelliJ plugin where a user can make a mistake an cause an infinite loop, hanging the plugin.

The only thing I found to work in most cases is `Thread.stop()`. Even that does not work for a script like this:

```
while(true) { 
   try { 
       java.lang.Thread.sleep(100); 
   } catch (e) {  
   } 
}
```

javascript catches the java.lang.ThreadDeath exception and keeps going. I found that the above sample is impossible to interrupt even with several `Thread.stop()` issued one after the other. Why would I use several? Hoping that one of them will catch the thread in its exception processing code and abort it. Which does work if there is something in the catch block to process as simple as `var i = "" + e;` that is enough to cause the second Thread.stop() to end it.

So the moral of the story is there is no fail safe way of ending a runaway script in Nashorn, but there is something that will work on most cases.

My implementation issues a `Thread.interrupt()`, then politely waits 2 seconds for the thread to terminate and if that fails then it issues `Thread.stop()` twice. If that does not work, then nothing else will either.

Hope it helps someone eliminate hours of experimentation to find a more reliable method to stop nashorn runaway scripts than hoping on the cooperation of the running script to respect `Thread.cancel()`.

Answer (score 2):

I have a similar problem where I let users write their own scripts.
But before I allow the script to be executed, I parse the script.
and if I find any of the following 
    (System.sleep. Exit, Thread.sleep, goto) etc
I don't even start the script, and I give user an error.

and then I do a search for all 
    (for,loops, while, doWhile), and I inject a method.
    checkForLoop() just after the loop identifier.
I inject checkForLoop(); into allow user submitted script.

```
    while(users code)
    {
    }  
becomes 
    while ( checkForLoop() && users code )
    {
    }
```

This way before every iteration of their loop, my method is called.
and I can count how many times I was called or check internal timers.
Than I can stop the loops or timers from inside checkForLoop();

Honestly I think its a big security issue anyway, just to blindly let users write script and just execute it.
You need to build in a system that injects your code into their code loops.
Which is not that hard.

There are 100s of safety mechanisms you can apply to users submitted code, there is no RULE that says you need to run their code as is.

I have edited this answer to include a very simple example.

//Step 1
put the users submitted JS code into a Java String called userJSCode;

Step 2
//inject code at the start of their code.

```
String safeWhile ="var sCount=0; var sMax=10;
function safeWhileCheck(){ sCount++;
if ( return ( sCount > sMax )}";

userJSCode = safeWhile + userJSCode;
```

//Step 3: inject the custom while code

```
String injectSsafeWHile = "while( safeWhileCheck() && ";
userJSCode = userJSCode.replace("while(", injectSsafeWHile);
```

//Step 4: execute custom JS code

```
nashhorn.execute(injectSsafeWHile);
```

//Here is users bad submitted code, note no i increment in the loop, it would go on for ever.

```
var i=0;
while ( i <1000 )
console.log("I am number " + i);
```

**using the steps above we end up with**

```
var sCount=0;var sMax=10;
function safeWhileCheck(){
sCount++; 
return ( sCount > sMax )};

var i=0;
while ( safeWhileCheck() && i <1000 )
console.log("I am number " + i)"
```

Here the while loop only executes a max of 10 times, so whatever you set the limit to.

Comment: Nice approach, could you post a working example? Are you using some kind of instrumentation tools to inject the code?

Comment: I have edited the code above to work as an example, you would need to cover all additional loops etc, but its what we use the "while" loop scenario.

Comment: that's interesting. this way we could even listen to java interrupts. String userJs = "while (true) {  }";
      String injectSsafeWHile = "while( !java.lang.Thread.interrupted() && ";      
      userJs = userJs.replaceAll("while \\(", injectSsafeWHile);

Comment: this is terrible "advice". Trying to parse source code and determining halting problem is dumb.