# How can I provide a pseudo file system for r.js?

Tags: java, javascript, requirejs, sandbox, rhino

Ok, so [r.js](https://github.com/jrburke/r.js/) can run on [Rhino](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Rhino). Which is great.

To do the stuff it needs to do.

On rhino it basically uses `java.io.File`, `java.io.FileOutputStream` and `java.io.FileInputStream` to achieve the filesystem modifications that it needs to do.

(Background: I am working on delivering a better development experience for Maven based Java/Javascript developers. Being Maven, there is the power of convention and the power of being opinionated. You can see the progress at [jszip.org](http://jszip.org).)

So what I want to do is have the on-disk structure appear by magic as a virtual file system.

So on disk we will have a structure like so:

```
/
/module1/src/main/js/controllers/controller.js
/module2/src/main/js/models/model.js
/module3/src/main/js/views/view.js
/webapp/src/build/js/profile.js
/webapp/src/main/js/main.js
/webapp/src/main/webapp/index.html
```

The `/webapp/src/build/js/profile.js` should look something like this:

```
({
    appDir: "src",
    baseUrl:".",
    dir: "target",
    optimize: "closure",
    modules:[
        {
            name:"main"
        }
    ]
})
```

Such that

- when r.js asks for `new File("src/main.js")` I will actually give it `new File("/webapp/src/main/js/main.js")`
- when it asks for `new File("profile.js")` I will give it `new File("/webapp/src/build/js/profile.js")`
- when it asks for `new File("controllers/controller.js")` I will give it `new File("/module1/src/main/js/controllers/controller.js")`
- when it asks for `new File("target")` I will give it `new File("/webapp/target/webapp-1.0-SNAPSHOT")`.

I have no issue writing the three mock classes required, i.e. the ones to use in place of `java.io.File`, `java.io.FileInputStream` and `java.io.FileOutputStream`,

Some questions such as [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/93911/how-can-you-run-javascript-using-rhino-for-java-in-a-sandbox) have answers that point to things like ClassShutter, which I can see I could use like this:

```
        context.setClassShutter(new ClassShutter() {
            public boolean visibleToScripts(String fullClassName) {
                if (File.class.getName().equals(fullClassName)) return false;
                if (FileOutputStream.class.getName().equals(fullClassName)) return false;
                if (FileInputStream.class.getName().equals(fullClassName)) return false;
                return true;
            }
        });
```

To hide the original implementations.

The problem is then getting Rhino to resolve the sandboxed equivalents... I keep on getting

```
TypeError: [JavaPackage java.io.File] is not a function, it is object.
```

Even if I prefix the call with a prior execution of `java.io.File = org.jszip.rhino.SandboxFile` map my sandboxed implementation over the now missing `java.io.File`

I could even consider using search and replace on the loaded `r.js` file just prior to compiling it... but I feel there must be a better way.

Does anyone have any hints?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ok, after much experimentation, this seems to be the way to do this:

```
Scriptable scope = context.newObject(global);
scope.setPrototype(global);
scope.setParentScope(null);

NativeJavaTopPackage $packages = (NativeJavaTopPackage) global.get("Packages");
NativeJavaPackage $java = (NativeJavaPackage) $packages.get("java");
NativeJavaPackage $java_io = (NativeJavaPackage) $java.get("io");

ProxyNativeJavaPackage proxy$java = new ProxyNativeJavaPackage($java);
ProxyNativeJavaPackage proxy$java_io = new ProxyNativeJavaPackage($java_io);
proxy$java_io.put("File", scope, get(scope, "Packages." + PseudoFile.class.getName()));
proxy$java_io.put("FileInputStream", scope,
        get(scope, "Packages." + PseudoFileInputStream.class.getName()));
proxy$java_io.put("FileOutputStream", scope,
        get(scope, "Packages." + PseudoFileOutputStream.class.getName()));
proxy$java.put("io", scope, proxy$java_io);
scope.put("java", scope, proxy$java);
```

There is a helper method:

```
private static Object get(Scriptable scope, String name) {
    Scriptable cur = scope;
    for (String part : StringUtils.split(name, ".")) {
        Object next = cur.get(part, scope);
        if (next instanceof Scriptable) {
            cur = (Scriptable) next;
        } else {
            return null;
        }
    }
    return cur;
}
```

And where `ProxyNativeJavaPackage` is something like

```
public class ProxyNativeJavaPackage extends ScriptableObject implements Serializable {
    static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    protected final NativeJavaPackage delegate;
    private final Map<String, Object> mutations = new HashMap<String, Object>();

    public ProxyNativeJavaPackage(NativeJavaPackage delegate) {
        delegate.getClass();
        this.delegate = delegate;
    }

    @Override
    public String getClassName() {
        return delegate.getClassName();
    }

    @Override
    public boolean has(String id, Scriptable start) {
        return mutations.containsKey(id) ? mutations.get(id) != null : delegate.has(id, start);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean has(int index, Scriptable start) {
        return delegate.has(index, start);
    }

    @Override
    public void put(String id, Scriptable start, Object value) {
        mutations.put(id, value);
    }

    @Override
    public void put(int index, Scriptable start, Object value) {
        delegate.put(index, start, value);
    }

    @Override
    public Object get(String id, Scriptable start) {
        if (mutations.containsKey(id)) {
            return mutations.get(id);
        }
        return delegate.get(id, start);
    }

    @Override
    public Object get(int index, Scriptable start) {
        return delegate.get(index, start);
    }

    @Override
    public Object getDefaultValue(Class<?> ignored) {
        return toString();
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return delegate.toString();
    }

    @Override
    public boolean equals(Object obj) {
        if (obj instanceof ProxyNativeJavaPackage) {
            ProxyNativeJavaPackage that = (ProxyNativeJavaPackage) obj;
            return delegate.equals(that.delegate) && mutations.equals(that.mutations);
        }
        return false;
    }

    @Override
    public int hashCode() {
        return delegate.hashCode();
    }
}
```

That still leaves the original classes at `Packages.java.io.File` etc, but for the `r.js` requirement this is sufficient, and it should be possible for others to extend this trick to the general case.